# Load data for RNN model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, training-data

I have Images and labeled metadata that I want to merge together and train my RNN model on. The directory is set up as so

```
data/
    |
    |
     --> dataset1_images/
                 |
                  --> *.png (many files)
    | 
    |
     --> dataset1_labels/
                 |
                  --> *.json (many files)
    | 
    |
     --> dataset2_images/
                 |
                  --> *.png (many files)
    | 
    |
     --> dataset2_labels/
                 |
                 --> *.json (many files)
    |
    |
     --> dataset3_images/
                 |
                  --> *.png (many files)
    |
    |
     --> dataset3_labels/
                 |
                  --> *.json (many files)
```

There are files with extensions of .png and .json.

**How should I go about loading the data *given the above format* for an RNN model?**

-Thank you

Comment: Create 2 arrays, images and labels. Open each file and append to the appropriate array in the same order (ie open image file and append, then open corresponding label file and append). Start with this idea. If you get stuck, update the question with your code. Question though: what solution are you looking for, to use a RNN for images?

Comment: Thank you I that appending the images to a np.array was the best method.